# crashlytics "Answers" crashes when app starts

Tags: android, crashlytics

i added crashlytics feature to my app but i got the following NullPointerException at:

com.crashlytics.android.answers.Answers.doInBackground(Answers.java:102)

The app does not crash so at least the app is safe... just wondering if anybody had the same issue

Thanks

Comment: what are you really saying?

Comment: Show us the code from line 102 inside Answers.java

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics here. Definitely seems like something odd is happening. Mind sending me a note at support@ so that we can dig into this?